# Add a ProgressBar to each item in my ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I display a `ListView` that should contain a `TextView` followed by a `ProgressBar` (underneath it).

So far I only display a `TextView`s like such:

In my `Activity.xml`:

```
<fragment
      android:id="@+id/routineFragment"
      android:name="kade_c.trakr.fragments.RoutineListFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In my `RoutineListFragment.java` that extends `ListFragment`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
            R.array.routine, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

And finally my `fragment_routine_list.xml` that contains my `ListView`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/RoutineLayout">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>    

</LinearLayout>
```

How may I add a `ProgressBar` under each `TextView` contained in my `ListView`?

Forgive me if this question is too broad, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

Comment: Instead of using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` layout use custom layout with ProgressBar

Comment: You'll need to create a custom adapter, so you can set the value for the text view and the progress bar.  See duplicate for details on that, or google "Custom listview adapter"